How to calculate Rslope for MAX25611
There isn't much information for calculating Rslope. THe only equation that includes Rslope is Vslope, which is being differentiated. Unsure how to approach this, as I seem to require it for my application which will require the controller to operate in CCM with > 50% duty cycle.
See below images, which are from the MAX25611 controller's datasheet



It's relatively straightforward.
Block Diagram from Datasheet

Functional Diagram from Datasheet, boost converter current sense section


The CS pin of the MAX26511 emits a current that has a ramp waveform; this waveform starts at 0 at the turn-on instant of the boost switch (MOSFET), and rises at a constant slope toward 50uA at the end of the clock period.  When this current passes through the resistor Rslope it adds a ramp voltage to the voltage on the current sense resistor.  This implements the ramp compensation that peak current-mode controllers require to maintain stability.
For the boost converter in this chip, the ramp compensation required is best expressed as follows:

By adding a compensating ramp equal to the down-slope of the inductor current, any tendency toward sub-harmonic oscillation is damped within one switching cycle.

Source:
Author: Robert Sheehan
Title : UNDERSTANDING AND APPLYING CURRENT-MODE CONTROL THEORY
Publication: Texas Instruments, Literature Number: SNVA555.
The down-slope will be determined by the voltage across the boost inductor when the MOSFET is off, and the value of the boost inductor.
Example:  Let's assume the following:
Fs = 350kHz
Vin = 12V
Vout of the boost converter = 30V
The boost inductor = 50uH.
Then the downslope of the current in the inductor is:
di/dt = (30 - 12) / 50uH = 360xE3 A/s = 360A/ms = 0.36A/us.
The clock period = 1 / Fs = 1 / 350kHz = 2.8us.
Hence slope of the current ramp out of CS pin =  50uA / 2.8us = 17.9uA/us.
Now, let's assume the average current in the inductor is 1A. The waveform of this current will be a pedestal (constant) plus ramp, with:
valley at (1 - 0.18A) = 0.82A, and
peak at (1 + 0.18A) = 1.18A.
Let's say you have selected a peak current limit of 2A, so the current sense resistor is:
0.418V / 2A = 209mΩ --> 200mΩ.
The Rslope resistor has to generate a voltage that gives the equivalent of 0.36A/us, when it carrying a current ramp with a slope of 17.9uA/us.
The voltage slope will be:
0.36A/us x 200mΩ = 72mV/us.
Hence Rslope = (72mV/us) / (17.9uA/us) = 72mV / 17.9uA  = 4.022kΩ.

How did you determine the ramp value of 0.18? I'm assuming that you assumed an arbitrary ripple ratio of 18%. But wouldn't that mean the peak current limit is 1.18A? How did you pick 2A in this example? But thanks, just by looking at the functional and block diagram, many things here make sense.

Can you expand a bit more on "implements the ramp compensation that peak current-mode controllers require to maintain stability" or reference some literature that I can read?

Yes, I recommend that reference from TI that I had mentioned in my answer.

Peak current limit is usually set above the design maximum average current by some margin.  The feedback control loop will find the correct value at the COMP pin.  It is not intended to be right at the peak of the current.  You need to ensure it operates over the full range of Vin, boost Vout, and load current.

Yes, the 0.18A ripple came from the 50uH inductor, the Fs (set by the chip), and the particular values of Vin & boost Vout.  I also chose 1A as an arbitrary load current.

Is it usual design practice to consider the inductor's peak current limit to be 100% average current? I know this is just an example, but I'm curious about actual practice when designing a system.

Is it usual design practice to consider the inductor's peak current limit to be 100% average current? Answer: no.   The inductor current limit, as set by the maximum permitted voltage on the CS pin, must always be above the maximum design average value, and by a significant margin, not by a few %.  Remember, this is an instantaneous current limit, when reached the switch turns off instantly, and the inductor current can never exceed this value.   Other lower limits can be imposed by outer control loops if necessary.
